# Javascript/Jquery Regex Split

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In Javascript, I am getting a string like I have a string exactly like 
`H01=13 H02=12 H03=43 H04=56.....` ?

I want to split the string and give it to the different textboxes in the page like

```
txtHeight01's value(text) is 13 
txtHeight02's value(text) is 12 
txtHeight03's value(text) is 43
```

Part of the code would be like

```
paddedcounter = i.padLeft(2, '0'); //(i is for(i=0;i<3;i++)
$('#txtHeight' + paddedcounter).val()=//These will the values from the splitted string.
```

Comment: you should crete the TB manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var strTest = 'H01=13 H02=12 H03=43 H04=56';
    var splitArrayBySpace = strTest.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < splitArrayBySpace.length; i++){
            var splitArraybyValue = splitArrayBySpace[i].split('=');
            $('#txtHeight' + splitArraybyValue[0]).val(splitArraybyValue[1]);
    }
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thats almost the answer. But when I write the following line:
`window.alert(splitArraybyValue[0] + " " + splitArraybyValue[1]);`
I get H01 13.....H02 12...I dont want H in there . So, I  modified your code a little to get he following:

`var splitArrayBySpace = temp.split(' ');for (var i = 0; i < splitArrayBySpace.length; i++) { j = j + 1;                  paddedcounter = j.padLeft(2, '0');var splitArraybyValue = splitArrayBySpace[i].split('='); $('#txtLength' + paddedcounter).val(splitArraybyValue[1]);}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regex, you can do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var string = 'H01=13 H02=12 H03=43 H04=56';
    var split = string.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0, length = split.length; i < length; i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].split('=');

        //Then you can do:
        $('#txtHeight' + i).val(split[i][1]);
    }

    console.log(split);
});
```

which give you this :

```
[["H01", "13"], ["H02", "12"], ["H03", "43"], ["H04", "56"]]
```

Comment: It gives me output like 'H' '0' '1' '1' '3'

Answer (score 0):

generate a key value object:

```
var arr = 'H01=13 H02=12 H03=43 H04=56'.split(' '),
    obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = arr[i].split('=');
    obj[val[0]] = val[1];
}

console.log(obj);
/* output Object
{
    H01: "13",
    H02: "12",
    H03: "43",
    H04: "56"
}
*/
```

than u can create string of your choice:

```
var text = [];
for (var j in obj) {
    var num = j.replace('H',''),
        value = obj[j];                        

    text.push('txtHeight' +j + '\'s value(text) is ' + value);
}
console.log(text.join('<br />'));
// output text
txtHeightH01's value(text) is 13<br />
txtHeightH02's value(text) is 12<br />
txtHeightH03's value(text) is 43<br />
txtHeightH04's value(text) is 56
```